# Draw highcharts with many year for xAxis

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, highcharts

i'm new with Highligh Charts and i want to create a chart like this:
[image]

Problem with me is how do i custom xAxis like the image?
Please help me to do it.
I use dotnet highlight chart.

Thank in advance.

**EDIT**:

This is source code:

```
DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
            .SetTitle(new Title()
            {
                Text = "Position of Cash/Group"
            })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis()
            {
                Title = new YAxisTitle()
                {
                    Text = ""
                },
                Labels = new YAxisLabels
                {
                    Formatter =
                    "function () {if(Math.abs(this.value)>=1000) return this.value / 1000 + 'k'; else return this.value;}"
                }
            })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                TickmarkPlacement = Placement.On,

                Categories =
                    new[] {"1/2016", "2/2016", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"},
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Data =
                    new Data(new object[]
                    {29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 1440.0, 176.0, 135.6, -1480.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4}),
                Color = Color.YellowGreen
            }).SetLegend(new Legend()
            {
                Enabled = false
            }).SetTooltip(new Tooltip()
            {
                Formatter = "function() {if(Math.abs(this.y)>=1000) return this.y / 1000 + 'k'; else return this.y; }"
            }).SetCredits(new Credits()
            {
                Enabled = false

            });
```

Comment: what is your code so far?

Comment: if I take a look at [this](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) example they use the line that you commented out (`//Categories =
`). What is wrong with that? Your picture shows that you need 2 lines of X-Label ticks is that right? is that your problem?

Comment: @Mong Zhu: no, i forgot to uncomment categories.

Comment: Take a look at the Grouped Categories plugin: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

Comment: It is not support for Dotnet.Highlighchart.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your clarification. The problem with dotnet.highcharts is, that grouped categories are not supported by it. See this [link](https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/discussions/435704) for a statement.

However you could generate this chart by using linebreaks in your array. Either you hardcode it into your array like `"May\r\n2016"` or you can write a function that edits your array to append the newline + year at the middle position or something like that. Maybe you need another newline command based on your environment but this would be an approach to fiddle around. Good luck!

---

You could use grouped categories, which allows you to create your desired xAxis label. Here is a [link](http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/) with an example from github.

Comment: I'm working with Dotnet.HighlightChart, it is not support for DotNet

Comment: did the edit help you in any way? did you make progress?